# Accessibility of an object in the template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Good day,
I have several buttons in my WPF application that use a pre-made style template.
In this template is once the content (text) and an image.
This image should be, depending on the button, a different one or no one.

The "Settings_Button" uses the style of the "Pagebutton".
This style contains how the button is built. There is also an Image in it. How do I access the source property of the image?

Unfortunately I haven't found a solution for this online and I'm still relatively new in this area.

[The Style Template, the Buttons are using]

```
<!--PageButton-->
        <Style x:Key="Pagebutton" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource Roboto}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource FntBtnColor_Page}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5 5 5 5"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border x:Name="borderBtn" CornerRadius="3" Background="#E00047" >
                            <Grid>
                              <Image x:Name="Pagebutton_Image" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="15" Width="15" Margin="0 0 20 0"/>
                              <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenterBtn" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Focusable="False" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                            
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

[The Usage of the Style]

```
<Button x:Name="Settings_Button" Style="{DynamicResource Menuebutton}" Content="{x:Static p:Resources.Menue_settings}" Click="Settings_Click"/>
```

Comment: Hi, please [edit] your question and post the code as code to allow easy debugging. If you're not sure how to ask a well received question, please read [ask]

Comment: A typical solution (prior to deriving a custom ImageButton control) is to bind the Image's Source property to the Tag property of the Button like `<Image Source="{TemplateBinding Tag}"/>` and assign the desired ImageSource to the Button's Tag when it is used, or in a derived Style.

Comment: @Clemens I have just tried. Unfortunately, this also does not load the image :/

Comment: You probably just assigned an image path to the Tag property. With a TemplateBinding there is no built-in type conversion from string to ImageSource. Either assign a BitmapImage to the Tag, or change the TemplateBinding to a regular one: `<Image Source="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>`